# How to play sound from media player when phone on vibration mode in android?

Tags: android

How to play sound from media player when phone on vibration mode in android?
i want to play ringtone in vibration mode.

Comment: This type of question belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/), assuming it can be worded to meet their [guidelines](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0):

When phone is on vibration mode (a.k.a silent mode), you can go to Settings -> Sound & notification -> and increase volume of Media volume.

Then you can locate the file you want to play, and play it with any music player app.